# Handling click on image button of listview from activity

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have a list view of songs with a play button
[image: Like this] ..
Now I need to click on this play buttons based on their positions and after click change the selected one into pause button .. but i have to do this inside my activity not in the adapter(getView).. Any suggestions !?

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      //productList is my ArrayList<Product> and
      //Product is my Serializable class that holds
      // items that is in mysql database
      Product selectedProduct = productList.get(position);


    }
});
```

Comment: Please be specific and update your question

Comment: I think my question is more than specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, use a recyclerview instead of a listview. Afterwards, inside the adapter in onBindViewHolder method, handle clicks by addind a click listener to holder :

```
holder.setOnClickListener(...);
```

interface:

```
public interface OnItemClicked{
    void onItemClicked(/*HERE YOUR VARIABLES TO PASS FROM ADAPTER TO MAINACTIVITY);
}
```

in adapter:

```
OnItemClicked listener;

public void setOnItemClickedListener(OnItemClicked listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

downwards, on onBindViewHolder method :

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onBindViewHolder(... params){
    ...your code

    holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(listener != null)
                listener.onItemClicked()
        }
    });
}
```

and, finally, in your MainActivity:

```
adapter.setOnItemClickedListener(new OnItemClicked ... ) <- here will pop up autocomplete
```

Comment: I just said that i  need to do this inside my activity

Comment: Ok then, create a custom interface and add a listener to it. Let me edit my post to show you how.

Answer (score -1):

use this in your activity

1. Declare RecyclerView and set Layout Manager
2. set Adapter

> view.setAdapter(mAdapter);

3. perform on click

v

```
view.addOnitemTouchListener(

new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                        //do something
                    }
                })
        );
```

**RecyclerItemClickListener :**

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

Comment: seems like copied from [here](http://sapandiwakar.in/recycler-view-item-click-handler/), you can do that but mention the source!

Comment: Cause `RecyclerItemClickListener` is a custom class. Not part of the RecyclerView API.

Comment: i used it but i don't know the source reference... by the way thanq